# Disable "Suppress the Mouse" when touch is injected

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 has this wonderful feature that it hides or "suppresses" the mouse when touching.

Well i'm writing a WPF application that is *injecting* touch, so I don't want to suppress the mouse.

So far I've tried using the cursor API (SetSystemCursor) to make the cursor reappear, but that hasn't worked.

Any help will be appreciated, even along the lines of "that is impossible, move on with your life".

Thanks.